# Passing rows and columns to functions

Tags: c++

I've written a function with a one dimensional array as input. In the main() part I need to pass rows of a two dimensional array as inputs to that function. I have no idea if that is possible and how (it is possible in Matlab, but in C++, I don't know). So, I appreciate it if any one will tell me.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your function signature is `void foo(int a[N])` and your input array is defined as `int x[M][N]`, you can pass the rows of it to `foo` by calling `foo(x[i])`, where `i` denotes the line number of your 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

I presume your function looks something like this:

```
void function(int row[]) { ... }
```

The first important thing to understand is that there's no such thing as a parameter of array type. The `row` parameter above may look like an array, but it's not. In fact, it's a pointer equivalent to `int* row`.

The second thing to understand is that the name of an array can be implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. Let's say you have an array `int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`, you could do `function(array)` to pass it to the function. However, you're not actually passing the array. What's really happening is that the `array` argument being passed is being converted to a pointer to its first element - so a pointer to the value `1` in the array. As we've just seen, the function parameter `row` is really a pointer, so it's fine to pass this pointer to the first element to it.

Now, I imagine you have a two dimensional array that looks something like:

```
int array[N][M] = { ... };
```

If we consider `N` to be the number of rows and `M` to be the number of columns (you could imagine it either way round, but this is consistent with your matlab knowledge), you know that `array[0][1]` will access the second element on the first row (because we index from 0 in C++). If you just provide a single subscript, like `array[0]`, this represents an entire row of the two dimensional matrix. That expression, `array[0]`, is an array of `int`s. Since this array of `int`s can be converted to a pointer to its first element, you can pass `array[0]` and the function will receive, as `row`, a pointer to the first element of the first row (or `0`th row).

So you can then do:

```
function(array[0]);
```

However, because the `row` is really a pointer, inside the function you've lost any idea about what size the array actually is. It is typical to pass along the size of the array at the same time:

```
void function(int row[], int size);

function(array[0], M);
```

However, it is generally not the best practice in idiomatic C++ to use array types like this. We prefer to use containers provided by the standard library. For example, a `std::array<std::array<int, M>, N>` is a nice fixed size 2-dimensional array analog:

```
void function(std::array<int, M> row);

std::array<std::array<int, M>, N> array;
// Fill array...
function(array[0]);
```

Now you don't have to pass along the size of the array, because the `std::array` and other standard container types provides mechanisms for getting the size.

Answer (score 1):

Passing a column to a function can be done quite easily:

```
void gimmeColumn(int x[]) {}

int main() {
    int table[10][10];
    int columnToPass = 3;
    gimmeColumn( table[columnToPass] );
}
```

However, passing a row in a similar fashion is not possible. You could consider writing your own class to facilitate this behavior.

```
template<type T>
class SelectableTable {
private:
    T** table;
    int rows, columns;
public:
    SelectableTable( int numRows, int numColumns )
    :
        rows( numRows ),
        columns( numColumns )
    {
        table = new T*[columns];
        for( int i=0; i<columns; i++ )
            table[i] = new T[rows];
    }

    ~SelectableTable() {
        for( int i=0; i<columns; i++ )
            delete[] table[i];
        delete[] table;
    }

    T* operator[](int column) {
        return table[column];
    }

    int getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    int getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    TableRow selectRow(int row) {
        return TableRow<T>( *this, row );
    }
};

template<type T>
class TableRow {
private:
    int row;
    SelectableTable<T>& table;
public:
    TableRow( SelectableTable<T>& fromTable, int selectedRow )
    :
        table(fromTable),
        row(selectedRow)
    {}

    T& operator[](int column) {
        return table[column][row];
    }

    int size() {
        return table.getColumns();
    }
};
```

And then you can simply use this as such:

```
void gimmeRow( TableRow<int> row ) {
    for( int i=1; i<row.size(); i++ )
        row[i] = row[i-1];
}

int main() {
    SelectableTable<int> table(10,10);
    int rowToPass = 3;
    gimmeRow( table.selectRow(rowToPass) );
}
```

Of course, to get this code to work, you should add some forward declarations, best using headers. For uniformity, you could also implement a class `TableColumn`.

Comment: Note that this assumes row-major usage.